# page size in search result component not working as expected

Tags: sxa-search, computed-field

i just create new computed field for sorting search result alphabetical ascending, but when i put page size for result as example 8 it displays only 3 in page load,  while if i used any other field in sorting it's working fine , i don't know why!
[image]

Comment: Check the Solr query for the search log and compare it with the working one. Also, try to rebuild the index and validate records in Solr Abmin UI.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for an error like that is the fact that your index is not in sync with your database.

In your index there are items which are not in database anymore - Solr returns a set of documents but when SXA tries to map them to Sitecore items, they are not in database, so the results displayed on your website show less items then requested.

Solution? If that's a reason of your issues, simply **rebuild the index** to make sure it's in sync with what is in your database.